# Purge process_execution, instance and instance_label_map data?

Tags: docker, rancher

**Rancher Version:** 1.1.3
**Docker Version:** 1.12.1
**Environment Type: (Cattle/Kubernetes/Swarm/Mesos)** Cattle

My Rancher Server database is getting bigger and bigger. I would like to clean it up.

I've read about purging old database entries here http://docs.rancher.com/rancher/v1.2/en/faqs/server/#rancher-server-database-is-growing-too-quickly
and changed the setting `audit_log.purge.after.seconds`.

However for the other big players `process_execution`, `instance_label_map` and `instance` there is no such setting. ***How can I purge data from those?***

***Also can I start the cleaning process manually?***

[image: node ssh 2016-09-17 01-48-04]